# jquery effects are NOT working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have some experience in PHP but not in JQuery that much.

My admin.php page has a div which has id named "table1" where content gets loaded via ajax:

```
document.getElementById("table1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

xmlhttp gets data from sorgula1.php page which has some JQuery effects like highlighting table rows. When I'm trying to run the sorgula1.php alone, the highlighting works but when it is loaded via ajax to admin.php, highlighting and other JQuery effects are not working. I've tried everything to make it work but, I always failed. 
For those of you who will ask me to remove the  $(document).ready(function() statement, I'm informing you that it doesn't work.

Here is the sorgula.php code: [sorgula1.php](http://pastebin.com/pUYA5nqx)

please be specific about the answers guys.Thanx for all answers.

Comment: You may wish to read up on [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to help cleanup your code.

Comment: I hope all the answers are specific enough for you. If not, I'll take it up with the boys back at headquarters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe when you use `innerHTML` property, the javascript doesn't work. I think you can solve this problem by using jQuery `load()` function.

Comment: Thank you EmCo, its working after I used Query load function instead of innerHTML function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the elements loaded via ajax do not have the effects applied to them - have you tried calling the $("#myTable").tablesorter(); javascript (again) after the ajax response has been received and injected into the DOM?

Edit sorry it should probably be this code that you call:

```
$("tr").not(':first').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("background","yellow");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css("background","");
  }
);
```

or use .live()

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your events to [Live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). I would say that it doesn't work, because elements are loaded after the jQuery functions are registered. So try

```
$("tr").not(':first').live('hover',function(){ // CODE });
```

Comment: I have written this code and run it but it didn't even respond me. am I doing something wrong? code: $("tr").not(':first').live('hover',function(){ $(this).css("background","yellow");},function(){$(this).css("background","");});